# Regex: dont match if preceeded by char in range x

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use Regex (c#) to do the following:

- Only match if search string `'70'` is not preceded by `ID="` (case insensitive)
- And only match if string before search string `'70'` does not contain `'+'`

Example Text (linebreaks only for visuals):

```
ID="70" Testtext
MultilingualText Uid="70"
Test="+#12-A170"
CV_70
```

i got the first condition via

```
(?i)(?<!ID=\")70
```

which will only match `70` in line 3 & 4 but i have no idea how to exclude the line containing the `'+'`. The position of `'+'` is variable in front of the search string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use

```
(?i)(?<!\+.*)(?<!ID=")70
```

The pattern matches

- `(?i)` Modifier for case insensitive
- `(?<!\+.*)` If a `+` is not on the left
- `(?<!ID=")` If `ID+` is not directly to the left of the current position
- `70` Match 70

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%28%3f%3c!%5c%2b.*%29%28%3f%3c!ID%3d%22%2970&i=ID%3d%2270%22+Testtext%0d%0aMultilingualText+Uid%3d%2270%22%0d%0aTest%3d%22%2b%2312-A170%22%0d%0aCV_70%0d%0a)

```
string pattern = @"(?i)(?<!\+.*)(?<!ID="")70";
string input = @"ID=""70"" Testtext
    MultilingualText Uid=""70""
    Test=""+#12-A170""
    CV_70";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Output

```
70
```

**Update**

The final working pattern as commented by @[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) matching any char except double quotes

```
(?i)(?<!\+[^"]*)(?<!ID=")70
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%28%3f%3c!%5c%2b%5b%5e%22%5d*%29%28%3f%3c!ID%3d%22%2970&i=ID%3d%2270%22TesttextMultilingualTextUid%3d%2270%22Test%3d%22%2b%2312-A170%22CV_70evenmoretext70_123test%0d%0a%0d%0aID%3d%2270%22+Testtext%0d%0aMultilingualText+Uid%3d%2270%22%0d%0aTest%3d%22%2b%2312-A170%22%0d%0aCV_70%0d%0a)

Comment: The pattern seems to be correct, but I dont get any match using my string. I found out that it does not contain any new lines which I think is the cause..

Comment: @Joe What is the string that you are using? Can you add it to this demo, save it and paste the new link back again here in the comments? https://regex101.com/r/VY6sTT/1

Comment: Very good use of dynamic length lookbehind

Comment: @anubhava linebreaks again. You altered the string

Comment: is there a pattern for: match if amount x of preceding chars do not include '+'? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Joe You can use a fixed length, but that would be error prone https://regex101.com/r/Cjyoii/1 Ruling out matching a `"` like anubhava suggested seems a better approach.

Comment: @anubhava Your suggestion seems to solve the issue. You can post it if you want.

Comment: No no, that was built on top of your regex. Please edit your answer if that has worked out for OP.